# Cant use strcmp

Tags: c

so im trying to build a coe that checks for anagrams using a string that adds one each time a letter shows up in the original string.

im doing this by comparing two strings with strcmp but for some reason i always get that the strings are equal even when theyre not, would really appreciate some feedback.

thanks!

```
int firstWord[] = { 0 }, secondWord[] = { 0 }, len, i, j, anagrams=0;
char string[1000];

gets_s(string, sizeof(string));
len = strlen(string);
i = 0;
while (i < len) {
    if (string[i] == ' ') {
        for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            secondWord[string[j]]++;
        }
    }
    if (string[i] != ' ')
        firstWord[string[i]]++;
    if (strcmp(firstWord, secondWord) == 0) {
        anagrams++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Look at your code to fill `firstWord` and `secondWord`, I don't think they are doing what you think they are doing...

It **looks** to me like `firstWord` will end up with all characters that aren't spaces. And that `secondWord` have the contents of the line starting from the character after a space.

Comment: what is the actual objective you want to achieve...its not very clear...but a word of advice...try to avoid having index of array as a character...you could lend in great troubles and also in very unexpected results

Comment: @ShreyanMehta hi thanks for the replay. im trying to count how many times each letter appears in a given word so that i can check to see if two words are anagrams of eachother, the thing is that the comparison wont work for some reason, it keeps going in the if (strcmp(firstWord, secondWord) == 0) for some reason

Comment: strcmp() requires character arrays, not integer arrays... It compares strings, not values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays `firstWord` and `secondWord` each only have a single `int` in capacity. Arrays are not dynamically resized like your code assumes.

```
int firstWord[] = { 0 }
```

This code means to create an array with exactly **one** element in it with the value `0`.

The following lines:

```
firstWord[string[i]]++;
secondWord[string[j]]++;
```

both corrupt random memory and **do not** extend the array at all.

Comment: alright thanks, but when i change the strings to for example firstWord[300], secondWord[300] it still doesnt work

Comment: @user7792712 try printing the contents of `firstWord` and `secondWord` just before the `strcmp` to see if you are comparing what you think you are.

Comment: random numbers? Are you printing them as `printf("%s")` ? You are working with strings right? Either way, I would need to to better describe what you intend to do better to give more specific advice.

Comment: ill try to explain better, im receiving a sentence from the user and trying to determine if there any anagrams in the sentence. my idea was to check how many times each letter appears in each word by using firstWord and secondWord

Comment: by sentence do you mean a line with just two words? or will there legitimately be several words?

Comment: then id compare the strings using strcmp, if theyre the same then its an angram, if not keep going to the next word. its obviously not done yet, for now i tought itwould at least work with 2 words...

Comment: eventually there would be several ords, but if i manage to get it to ork with 2 words i imagine i could make it work with more

Comment: So the format will be: <base word> <comp1> <comp2> ... ?

As in all "comp" words are being tested if they are anagrams of the "base" word?

Comment: exactly, and after i finish with the first word i would move on to the next

Comment: So, it seems that your approach is to compare character historgrams for each word. Same historgram means that it's an anagram.

If I were you, I would try to correctly capture the first word's histogram and see if you do that correctly. Then it should be easy to convert that code to work for subsequent words, since it would be the same code as the first word, just starting at a different index of the string.

Comment: right, i tought i was capturing it correcty, i guess im not. ill look into it thanks!